# Create two immutable objects with the same value in Python

Tags: python, immutability

Is it possible in Python to create two immutable objects with the same value?

So that you understand what I mean, here are some examples:

```
>>> a = 13
>>> b = 13
>>> a is b
True


>>> a = 13
>>> b = 26/2
>>> a is b
True


>>> a = 13
>>> b = int.__new__(int, 13)
>>> a is b
True


>>> a = 13
>>> b = int("13")
>>> a is b
True
```

Is it possible to create `a` and `b` with the same value but `a is b` to return `False`?
Just learning.... :D

Comment: Were you asking just for your own enlightenment, or did you have a use case in mind? Ordinarily you shouldn't care if it's two objects or one.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I was reviewing Python's data model and playing with some code for a better understanding when my brain tripped on the above :D. There is no use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just choose a value that is too large to be cached:

```
>>> a = 256
>>> b = 256
>>> a is b
True
>>> a = 257
>>> b = 257
>>> a is b
False
>>> a = "hey"
>>> b = "hey"
>>> a is b
True
>>> a = "hey!"
>>> b = "hey!"
>>> a is b
False
```

Only small integers and short strings will be cached (and this is implementation-dependent, so you shouldn't rely on that anyway). `is` should only be used for testing object *identity*, never for testing *equality*.

Comment: I somehow thought that because the objects are immutable they are reused (somewhat like String literals in Java) when in fact it's caching. Hmmm... Interesting. Just one quick question: So the only way I can be sure (no matter the implementation) that `a is b` is always `True` is to have `a = 13` then `b = a`. Correct?

Comment: Exactly, because then they both refer to the same object (in this case an integer). This of course works for all objects (after `a = b = 257`, `a is b` returns `True`).

Comment: @ElenaT: Avoid relying on the behaviour of `is` for scalar values. See [Python “is” operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) for more information.