# How do I check in python if an element of a list is empty?

Tags: python, list, element

I have a list like

```
l = []
```

How do I check if l[i] is empty?

```
l[i] = ''
```

and

```
l[i] = ""
```

dont't work.

Comment: An empty list is a list with no elements (`len(l) == 0`). Consider this would be true: `l = [""]; l[0] == ""` as would `l = [None]; l[0] is None`. Now, what's the goal/intent? :)

Comment: This is slightly ambiguous.  By "empty" do you mean that the index exists, but is the empty string?  Or that it doesn't exist at all, e.g. the number of elements is less than your index?

Comment: Have you tried the equality comparison operator? Like: `l[0] == ""`

Comment: You can't just say "X didn't work".
What was the specific comparison you did? What error did you get?

Comment: I know that the element l[i] exists, but how do I check if the String is empty? (I also tested l[i] == "" and it don't works.)

Comment: @bdhar that's the way I've done it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
if l[i]:
    print 'Found element!'
else:
    print 'Empty element.'
```

Comment: This is The Way.

Comment: what is it's zero?

Answer (score 4):

Just check if  that element is equal to None type or make use of NOT operator ,which is equivalent to the NULL type you observe in other languages.

```
if not A[i]:
    ## do whatever
```

Anyway if you know the size of your list then you don't need to do all this.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose

```
letter= ['a','','b','c']

for i in range(len(letter)):
    if letter[i] =='':
        print(str(i) + ' is empty')
```

`output- 1 is emtpy`

So we can see index 1 is empty.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if list element at index `i` is set or not, you can simply check the following:

```
if len(l)<=i:
    print ("empty")
```

If you are looking for something like what is a NULL-Pointer or a NULL-Reference in other languages, Python offers you `None`. That is you can write:

```
l[0] = None # here, list element at index 0 has to be set already
l.append(None) # here the list can be empty before
# checking
if l[i] == None:
    print ("list has actually an element at position i, which is None")
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in some laguages, `empty` is not a keyword in Python. Python lists are constructed form the ground up, so if element `i` has a value, then element `i-1` has a value, for all `i > 0`.

To do an equality check, you usually use either the `==` comparison operator.

```
>>> my_list = ["asdf", 0, 42, '', None, True, "LOLOL"]
>>> my_list[0] == "asdf"
True
>>> my_list[4] is None
True
>>> my_list[2] == "the universe"
False
>>> my_list[3]
""
>>> my_list[3] == ""
True
```

Here's a link to [the `strip` method](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.strip): your comment indicates to me that you may have some strange file parsing error going on, so make sure you're stripping off newlines and extraneous whitespace before you expect an empty line.

Comment: Apart from some syntax errors in your answer (fixed), it's a bad idea to teach people to use the `is` keyword for equality testing. It is used for object identity testing (and nothing else). Otherwise, [you're in for some confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158837/create-two-immutable-objects-with-the-same-value-in-python).

Comment: My mistake, for some reason I was under the impression that `None` comparisons used `is`. Maybe it's something I remembered from PHP or something...

Comment: Yes, because there is only one `None` object, so you use the `is` operator to explicitly test for object identity.

Comment: If I declare l.append(None), l[i] is None would work, but I read out of a file and l.append(linecache.getline(datei, number)) creates a new item but it cannot be proved if it's empty by using "is None".

Comment: Then you want the last case where `my_list[3] == ''`. Hint: did you make to strip newlines and other whitespace with `mystring.strip()`?

Answer (score 0):

I got around this with `len()` and a simple `if/else` statement.

List elements will come back as an integer when wrapped in `len()` (1 for present, 0 for absent)

```
l = []

print(len(l)) # Prints 0

if len(l) == 0:
    print("Element is empty")
else:
    print("Element is NOT empty")

Output:

Element is empty
```

Comment: ```python
if not l:
  print("empty")
else:
  print("contains data")
```
Its a bit shorter

Answer (score 0):

```
List = []

for item in List:
    if len(item.rstrip()) != 0:
        # Do whatever you want
```

This will be useful if you have long string list with some whitespace and you're not considering those list values.

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue where a location string needed some pre-testing:

```py
loc_string = "site/building/room//ru" # missing rack
is_ok = True
for i in loc_string.split('/'):
  if not i:
    is_ok = False

if is_ok:
  #perform any action
  print(is_ok)
```

This will return True if all values have data.